# Unable to receive message in worker service from azure service bus queue

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, .net-core-3.1, background-service, ihostedservice

Trying to implement consumer/receiver of message from Azure queue. I'm using worker service/backgroundservice project **.Net core 3.1**.

Following is the Program.cs

```
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IQueueClient>(x => new QueueClient(hostContext.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ServiceBusConnectionString") ?? hostContext.Configuration["ServiceBusConnectionString"], hostContext.Configuration.GetValue<string>("QueueName")));
            services.AddHostedService<WorkerService>();
        });
```

Following is the worker service.cs

```
public class WorkerService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IQueueClient queueClient;
    private readonly ILogger<PolCommunicationRequestQueueServiceBusSubscriber> logger;

    public WorkerService(IQueueClient queueClient, ILogger<WorkerService> logger)
    {
        this.queueClient = queueClient;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        try
        {
            queueClient.RegisterMessageHandler(ProcessMessagesAsync
            , new MessageHandlerOptions(ExceptionReceivedHandler)
            {
                MaxConcurrentCalls = 1,
                AutoComplete = false
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.LogError(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            await queueClient.CloseAsync();
        }
    }

    public async Task ProcessMessagesAsync(Message message, CancellationToken token)
    {
        // Process the message
        logger.LogInformation($"Received message: SequenceNumber:{message.SystemProperties.SequenceNumber} Body:{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body)}");
        await queueClient.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
    }

    public Task ExceptionReceivedHandler(ExceptionReceivedEventArgs exceptionReceivedEventArgs)
    {
        logger.LogError($"Message handler encountered an exception {exceptionReceivedEventArgs.Exception}.");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
  }
}
```

However a variation of the method worked but it is throwing an error "**A message handler has already been registered**."

```
while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    queueClient.RegisterMessageHandler((Message message, CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>
    {
        logger.LogInformation($"Received message: SequenceNumber:{message.SystemProperties.SequenceNumber} Body:{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body)}");

                    //Implement DB/other logic here
        return queueClient.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
    }, new MessageHandlerOptions(ExceptionReceivedHandler)
        {
            MaxConcurrentCalls = 1,
            AutoComplete = false
        });

    logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);

    await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
}
```

When I implemented it in a console project it works.
Not sure what is missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `StartAsync` and `StopAsync` of the `BackgroundService`.
`StartAsync` to register message handler. `StopAsync` to close the `queueClient`.
Otherwise, what happens is that you register the message handler and immediately close it, killing the connection to the broker.

With the variant that "worked" you have a tight loop so the client is not closed. But you re-register the same message handler multiple times, which is wrong.

Comment: I used StopAsync to close the queueClient and it worked. I would like to know why use StartAsync to register message handler but not ExecuteAsync? StartAsync makes sense but would like to know reasoning. I will accept your answer either way.

Comment: Start is about preparations and initialization. Execute is for the ongoing work. You'd need Execute method if you'd pump/receive messages manually. Since you register a handler, it's done on your behalf as a constantly running task. Therefore you don't need to re-register the handler time after time. Start to register the handler. Stop to close the client. And Execute is a no-op.